Wireguard not working on an Active Directory user
While doing preliminary tests to begin implementing Active Directory on a company's computers, I have encountered a problem when using the Wireguard VPN (which is used internally to access files on the company's local network remotely). Before adding the computer to the AD domain, Wireguard works without problems. But after adding the computer to the domain and logging in with one of the AD users, I get the following error when opening Wireguard:

I have already tried reinstalling the VPN from the AD user, adding the user to the 'Network Configuration Operators' group from the AD user manager on the server, I even tried applying a DWORD key in the regedit but Wireguard does not appear.

Pls logon to the client computer with LOCAL Administrator account and from User Manager on the client computer, add the Active Directory domain user that you logon and run the software, to the built-in Local Administrators Group. Then logoff and logon with the domain user and run the software.

How do I do that? I don't see the domain user in any of the Users accounts in my LOCAL Administrator account. Also, if I do what you say, the domain user will get other Administrator privileges that it shouldn't.

If I did not misunderstand, the above message says that the user executing the software must be a member of Local Administrators group, you can run 'Cmd' as Admin then execute "net localgroup Administrators /ADD  domainA\user1" to achieve this. It is the software that you have installed requiring the user to be a Local Admin according to the popup message above.

Ok, that fixed my problem with Wireguard and I can now run it as a domain user without any issues. But now, the domain user has admin privileges, which they cannot have for security reasons. I need a way for domain users to be able to access Wireguard, but with restricted access or no admin privileges.

It all depends upon the software. The vendor of the software should have a formal procedure for a non-administrator user to run the software . Just wanted to clarify Windows / Active Directory part.

Is there a local administrator on the computer? You can install Wireguard under that user.
You must have an AD group for techs, maybe Domain Admins, add that to the Local Users group on the workstation. You should be able to log in as a member of Domain Admins and install Wireguard.
In both cases, Wireguard will install and run fine, but the user won't be able to interact with it. If something goes wrong with it, all they can do is reboot.
